# How to force list not showing several decimal places after point?

Tags: python

i have the following problem. Whenever i want to print this list,

```
total_sums = []

for total_list in total_values:
    numeric_values = [x for x in total_list if isinstance(x, (int, float))]
    total_sum = sum(numeric_values)
    total_sums.append(total_sum)`
```

serval 0's after the deicmal place are also displayed even though i rounded the numbers before.

`[3.2, 4.1000000000000005, 3.3000000000000003, 3.9000000000000004]`

Why does this happen and how to force only showing one number after the decimal point?

Did my own research on here!

Comment: If the automatic output formatting doesn't work for you, then you just need to do to it yourself.  `print(' '.join("%.1f" % t for t in total_sums))`.

Comment: `even though i rounded the numbers before` - where? That is not in the code. And the output says they are not rounded.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to print one zero after dot:

```
float(f"{sum(numeric_values):0.1f}")
```

you can change 1 to every number you want...

but, I have another idea, use decimal: `float(Decimal(str(0.1)) + Decimal(str(0.2)))`

```
from decimal import Decimal
numeric_values = [Decimal(str(x)) for x in total_list if isinstance(x, (int, float))]
total_sum = float(sum(numeric_values))
    total_sums.append(total_sum)`
```